# SWIFT randomize array elements and button name

Tags: arrays, xcode, button, swift, random

So I am facing two problems:

I'm trying to get a random element out of an array. I've found this way:

```
var cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

var randomCard = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count)))
```

however, I get two errors:

```
"Expected ',' separator" 
"Expected expression in list of expressions".
```

What am I doing wrong?

The second issue is following:
I have `UIButtons` named `card1`, `card2`, `card3` and so on.
Is there any way to use a button corresponding to the `randomCard`?
Like for example for the image there is:

```
    UIImage(named: String (format: "card_%i_%i", y, b))
```

Comment: Your first code example works for me without any problems. Is that your actual code? As for the second question, no, you can't get to a variable from a `String` version of the variable's name. Instead, create an array of your buttons and randomly choose from that. (Or use the random index selected earlier.)

Comment: yes, this is my actual code. I've just created a new project, copied the code above and I get exactly the same errors.
I didn't know one can create an array of buttons, thanks :)

Comment: great, an array of buttons also doesn't work.   

created in a new project:
   `@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
    
    var array: [UIButton] = [button1, button2, button3]`
error:
"'ViewController.Type' doesn't have a member named 'button1'"

Comment: What do you mean use a button corresponding to random card? Do you want to hide the other buttons when they are not used?

Comment: @user3822605 no, I wanted to change the background of the button which number has been picked from an array. For example if the random number is 2, then change the background of the button2, if the number is 7, change the background of button7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize you were giving these as stored property declarations. The trouble you're running into is that when declaring stored properties, you can't access another property from the same class - `self.cards` doesn't exist at that time.

A couple ways to do this are by marking the second property as `lazy`, so the expression won't be evaluated until after the instance has been created, or creating it as a computed property, which gets the value each time it's accessed:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // stored property:
    var cardsArray = [1, 2, 3]
    // lazy property:
    lazy var cardCount: Int = self.cardsArray.count
    // computed property:
    var randomCard: Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.cards.count)))
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! it explains a lot and my code finally works fine. button array also works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements to test what random number is and then change the buttons background depending on which on it is. For example you could do something like this:

```
if randomCard == 1 {
//run some code
} else if randomCard == 2 {
//run some other code
}
```

and so on until you get all your values.

Comment: Yes, I know that, however, it's a really long solution if one has e.g. 50 cards. One way or the other, my main problem now is that I can't really use arc4random_uniform for I always get some errors.
Even such a simple code doesn't work: `class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var cardsArray = [1, 2, 3]
    
    var cardsLeft = cardsArray.count
    
}` What am I doing wrong? My questions may seem stupid but I am a beginner when it comes to swift and it's really not motivating when such a simple code gives you errors...

Comment: Are all of your buttons created programmatically?

Comment: no, I create them in Main.storyboard and then of course I connect them with my ViewController. But the code I gave you in my previous comment doesn't have any buttons, only two variables, and it doesn't work. It says that 'ViewController.Type' doesn't have a member named 'cardsArray'.

Comment: I've found some solution: is it simply that we can't use functions like count or arc4random inside of a class ViewController? So one need to create a function in the class ViewController and inside of this function one can use count, arc4random etc?

Comment: OK, I see what's going on. Will answer shortly.